# Change selector while a pan gesture is going on

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView C which is a subview of UIView B wich is a subview of UIView A. I add a UIPanGestureRecogizer to UIView C with a selector called "selectorX" and I want that when UIView C goes out of UIView A frame, then its superview changes to UIView A and I want also to change its UIPanGestureRecognizer with another selector "selectorY".

This is my code:

```
-(void)selectorX:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender{


     CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
     sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x, sender.view.center.y +translation.y);
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:sender.view];

    UIView *uiViewC=(ImagenFichaView *)sender.view;
    if (sender.view.center.y+translation.y<-50) {
         [uiViewC removeFromSuperView]
         CGPoint newCenter=[sender locationInView:uiViewA];
         [uiViewA addSubview:uiViewC];
         uiViewC.center=newCenter;
         UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectorY:)];
    panRecognizer.delegate=self;
    [uiViewC removeGestureRecognizer:sender];
    [uiViewC addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    }
```

}

Everything goes well but the transition between the 2 UIPanGestureRecognizers is not continuous. When uiViewC changes its superView, the drag action stops. I have to take off my finger from the screen and start the movement again. What can I do to make the movement continuos?
Thank you very much

Comment: instead of `[uiViewC removeFromSuperView]` use `[uiViewB removeFromSuperView]`

Comment: But I don't want to remove uiViewB, I want to keep it.

Comment: Why don't you wait until the end of the gesture before doing these view changes?

Comment: Because I want to move uiViewB when I change uiViewC's superview. And if I don't change its superview, uiViewC moves with uiViewB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a continuous movement I didn't remove uiViewC from uiViewB, I just added it to uiViewA and it solved the problem.